# Glossary title not showing

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to use glossaries but it is not displaying the title and only some terms. Tried to minify my document as much as possible

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={Term},plural={terms},description={A special word}}

\begin{document}

This is a special \gls{term}.

\printglossary[title=List of Terms,toctitle=Terms and Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

Comment: With your code I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVnO1.png What do you get?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's weird. Using BaKoMa TeX I get the same issue as with the non-minfied version

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Could my editor be at fault here? I am relatively new to the Latex-Concept

Comment: Usually no, as editors are frontends  to an underlying TeX distribution (typically TeX Live, MikTeX or MacTeX). For Bakoma it might be a bit different, as it seems to include its own TeX distribution, but I've never used it, and don't really know much about it. Does it have any tools for updating packages?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I wasn't able to find any so I gave up and started using Overleaf instead. Seems to be working just fine now